# first chance exception system.web.httpexception file does not exist

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, exception

I am new to Web programming so in the start i made a html resume in notepad and now i am trying to use Visual Studio 2010 and embed that html page(resume) in it .When i executed the website 
some directory listings was opened in chrome ,when i checked the debug output following exception was there

```
 A first chance exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll
```

After that i made two changes 
1-i selected a start page
2-Checked the

```
       CLR exceptions > System.web > System.Web.HttpException exception
```

as thrown from Debug->Exceptions

After that i got same error as unhandled exception with the two options Continue or Break and additional information:File does not exists

These are my html tags

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"            "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
    <title>Official CV</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function displayDate() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Date();
    }
   </script>
   </head>
   <body>
   <p id="demo">This is paragraph.</p>
   <button type="button" onclick="displayDate()"> Display Date</button>
   <table>
   <tr>
   <td>
   <h1>Abbas</h1>
   <address> House no 659, Street no 62, G-11/2, I </address>
   00923215250936
   </br>
   <h4>

   </br>
  <a id="#tips" href="http://abbasnaqvi512.tumblr.com/"> Go to my site </a>
  </h4>
 </td>
 <td>
 <img src="C:\Users\Abbas\Documents\My Web Sites\WebSite1\abbasShah.jpg"  width="104" height="142" alt="Abbas " > 
 </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 <a id="Top"></a>
 <a href="#Bottom">Bottom</a>

<hr/>

<table border="1">
<caption>Education</caption>
<tr style="background-color:yellow">
<th>Degree Name</th><th>School</th><th>City</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> BS </td> <td> N</td><td>I</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>F</td> <td> P</td> <td>S</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>M</td><td>C</td><td>S</td>
</tr>
</table>

<a id="Bottom"></a>
<a href="#Top">Top</a>

</body>
</html>
```

I didn't write anything in .cs file
I cant not understand most of the stuff i searched. kindly help me to understand my roblem and solve it .

Comment: Does `WebForm1.aspx.cs` exist?  Why are you using ASP.NET if you have no server-side controls?

Comment: @DStanley I added WebForm1.aspx as an item so it exists and first four lines are same as already written

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have a code-behind file just take out the `CodeBehind` and other server-side attributes from your `Page` directive:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#"%>
```